# select all posts with different post id in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  *
FROM  post  p
JOIN  user  u ON  p.user_id  =  u.id  
JOIN  friendships f ON  f.friend_id  =  u.id  
WHERE  f.user_id  =  1  OR  u.id  =  1  
ORDER  BY  p.created_at  DESC;
```

working on a projects where I'm trying to get all the post of the user as well as the user currently on.
So far i have this query working but is giving me duplicate posts of users.id = 1

is a user self join many to many where each user become friends and each user has their posts

Comment: That's what JOINs will do to ya. I recommend studying the basics of relational algebra.

Comment: SQL has `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: I tried using DISTINCT but i could not make it work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because you select all columns from all tables involved. 
Now for every new friendship with friend_id=1 you will receive a new record, with post duplicated. I guess you need:
`select distinct p.*`